# how do i use the data my click handler sends me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i am here again asking more questions i am making an interactive list where i want the user to click on the item he wants and it will take him to a page with more info about it
i have and even handler and when i click on my button i don't get strings instead tons of data

i am new to javascript and all so i am sorry if i miss some things
here is my code below

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Table}from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Button, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {  Image, List } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { left } from '@popperjs/core';
export default class CreateExercise extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
     this.state = {
      name:''
  
    }
  
  }
  
handleClick(e){
  console.log(e)
  window.location='/major/'+e
}

render() {
  
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>    
     <ul onClick={this.handleClick}>
    {['Adolescence Education: Chemistry (7-12)', 
'Adolescence Education: Social Studies (7-12)',
 'Biological Sciences', 
'Chemistry',
'English', 
'History', 
 'Industrial and Labor Relations',
'Liberal Arts', 
 'Media and Communications',
'Philosophy and Religion',
  'Politics & Economics & Law', 
'Spanish Language',
 'Visual Arts', 
'Adolescence Education: Biology (7-12)', 
'Adolescence Education: Mathematics (7-12)', 
'Biochemistry',
'Business Administration',
 'Childhood Education (1-6)', 
'Computer & Information Science', 
'Criminology', 
'Finance',
'General Studies', 
'Health and Society', 
'Industrial and Labor Relations',
'Management Information Systems', 
 'Marketing', 
'Mathematics', 
'Psychology', 
'Sociology', 
'Special Education and Childhood Education (1-6)', 
 'Visual Arts: Electronic Media'].map((item) =>  {

      return <li  key={item}>{item}<button type="button"
      onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)} style = {{position: 'absolute', left: '50%'}} >
      Click to view courses
    </button> </li> ;
    })}
  </ul>



    </div>
    

  
    
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you want to do. If you only want to retrieve the content of the clicked element, you can use this code snippet.

```
        import React, { Component } from "react";
        export default class CreateExercise extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
            this.state = {
              name: ""
            };
          }

          handleClick(e) {
            console.log(e);
            // window.location = "/major/" + e;
          }

          render() {
            const exerciseArray = [
              "Adolescence Education: Chemistry (7-12)",
              "Adolescence Education: Social Studies (7-12)",
              "Biological Sciences",
              "Chemistry",
              "English",
              "History",
              "Industrial and Labor Relations",
              "Liberal Arts",
              "Media and Communications",
              "Philosophy and Religion",
              "Politics & Economics & Law",
              "Spanish Language",
              "Visual Arts",
              "Adolescence Education: Biology (7-12)",
              "Adolescence Education: Mathematics (7-12)",
              "Biochemistry",
              "Business Administration",
              "Childhood Education (1-6)",
              "Computer & Information Science",
              "Criminology",
              "Finance",
              "General Studies",
              "Health and Society",
              "Industrial and Labor Relations",
              "Management Information Systems",
              "Marketing",
              "Mathematics",
              "Psychology",
              "Sociology",
              "Special Education and Childhood Education (1-6)",
              "Visual Arts: Electronic Media"
            ];
            return (
              <div>
                <ul>
                  {exerciseArray.map((item, key) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={key}>
                        {item}
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}>
                          Click to view courses
                        </button>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```